# Matrix of a transformation relative to a basis using eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Suppose $A$ is a 3x3 matrix and $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ is a basis of $R^3$ where:

$x_1$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue 6

$x_2$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue 2

$x_3$ satisfies $(A-2I)x_3=x_2$

Let $T: R^3 \to R^3$ be the linear transformation given by $T(y)=Ay$ and write the matrix of $T$ relative to the basis $X$. Show that $x_2$ and $x_3$ are both elements of the null space of $(A-2I)^2$.

I'm thinking that since $x_3$ satisfies $(A-2I)x_3=x_2$, then the eigenvalue 2 must be of multiplicity 2, telling me that the diagonalization of $A$ would be

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
6 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

which also tells me that the characteristic polynomial would be
$$ (x-6)(x-2)^2 = x^3-10x^2+28x-24$$

What I don't know how to do is find the matrix of $T$ relative to the basis $X$ without any further information, or how to find the null space of $(A-2I)^2$ without knowing what $A$ is. I would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is flawed. In fact, the existence of such a vector $x_3$ tells us that $A$ cannot be diagonailzed.

I would suggest that trying to "find the null space" is the wrong way to approach the problem. Instead, consider this: if I have a matrix $M$ and a vector $v$, how can I test whether $v$ is in the null space of $M$? It would be helpful to think about the definition of "the null space" of a matrix.